# How do I find the API calls in a C# plugin?

Tags: c#, .net, api

I am using a C# library that is a wrapper for a C++ Library that is suppose to be 1:1 but its not at all and has zero documentation. I need a way to find what calls are available without just manually going through it and seeing whats there during auto-complete?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a decompiler like [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and take a look at the source code of the C# library.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio (which sounds like you are since you mention auto-complete), you can use the **Object Browser** to inspect the assembly.